# Why is my cursor blinking constantly?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I just installed the full version of *Might and Magic Heroes VI*, and whether I'm in the menus or playing the game, my cursor is blinking constantly.  I've tried tinkering with all the graphics settings, but I can't make it stop.  I didn't have this problem with the demo.  Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: @wipq Ugh, no, then I'd have to download it from Steam all over again.

Comment: I've had this problem, too. I turned on V-Sync and it seemed to help quite a bit (but not completely.) Did you try this, and did it help?

Comment: Another possible solution would be to play in a window.

Comment: @Pubby8 - I get the same experience even in window'd mode.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - V-Sync helps a little.  Playing in a window doesn't change anything.

Comment: You could also try to limit your fps. This seems to help other users

Comment: Yah, I tried V-Sync but I didn't notice any difference.

Comment: i think it have problems only on specific graphic cards. i have probs on amd ati 4200. maybe on nvidia it works better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Ubisoft's [1.1.1 patch](http://might-and-magic.ubi.com/heroes-6/en-GB/news/details.aspx?c=tcm:21-29807&ct=tcm:6-231-32), this issue should be fixed!

> • Hot fix on default setting video option detection at start-up
>   causing possible dead locks on laptops
>
> • Blinking cursor fix
>
> • Fixing a version number issue

Comment: Still happening for me, hopefully that means that the patch just hasn't dropped yet, since I assume UPlay automatically applies it.

Comment: @bwarner if you have steam, steam will automatically download it (it did for me, and it solved the problem). If you don't have a steam version, I dunno how you get the patch.

Comment: Ah, I just remembered that I have Steam in offline mode right now, that probably explains it.

Answer (score 3):

This is currently an ongoing issue for a lot of players, Ubisoft is working on a no-ETA patch to fix this bug. So wait patiently till they manage to get it out.

Strangely I am one of the few people who do not have this issue.

Comment: It seems to happen intermittently.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to limit your FPS to 59 or lower. It seems to blink only with 60 FPS. People who own older machines and can't reach max FPS or don't have constant 60 FPS are not experiencing this bug.

Comment: How do I limit FPS?  Do I need to use a graphics card utility?

Comment: How did they not catch this before the release!?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for blinking cursor problem (for me it worked): right click on the desktop icon of Heroes 6 and click properties, then go to the compatibility tab, then tick the third and the fourth check boxes in "Settings" ("Disable visual themes" and "Disable desktop composition")

Answer (score 0):

The solution to a flickering cursor is the same for many Ubisoft games. I dont know why, but many Ubisoft games ran better when I **set my CPU affinity lower**. Setting my affinity to 2 instead of 4 cores stopped flickering and other issues. This fix worked in many other games (like Splinter Cell etc.).

Comment: How did this add to the other answers? In addition, I believe that the games should run better when you set the affinity higher to give it more processing power.